# Why my donut flies away when using Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 0

Tags: interface, shortcut

I am following the Blender Guru tutorial and I am stuck in camera view

1. I want to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>0</kbd> but my Donut coating flies away.
2. Why does my camera view become as illustrated bellow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Thanks I upload it!

Comment: I guess: ctrl+num0 sets active object as camera and ctrl+alt+num0 sets the camera at the view location... so it moves the selected object (the donut).

Comment: @ Taehyun Lee, you need to copy-paste here the link it will give you

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/f3660ecc346745529d1ec64db75291ab


oh sorry, It is my first Question so I made it mistke

Answer (score 6):

As said in comments, for some reason (probably using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num0</kbd>) you've set the donut as active camera.

Then, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Num0</kbd> you've placed the active camera (which is the donut) at the view location.

To set back the actual camera object as active camera, select it and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Num0</kbd> again.

Edit: to confirm that from your file, look at the scene properties:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  My camera was somehow in the 0,0,0 location.  To fix it:

1. I went into mode 'User Perspective (Local) Collection | Camera' by pressing 0.
2. I did a box selection of by dragging the cursor over BOTH donut and icing. (This is the key ingredient to get it working - no pun intended).
3. Then I pressed Ctrl+Option+NumPad0 on my Mac (which uses the Option key for Alt found on a PC).

This seems to stop the icing flying off and gives a proper camera view.

I am a beginner (also doing the same tutorial).  So my steps might be sub-optimal but it was the only way I could stop the icing flying off the donut.